# ArcPad 8.0 and Postgis Data - Viewing & Editing Problems!

Tags: qgis, postgis, arcgis-10.1, editing, arcpad

I have data held on a postgis which I want to take out onto site to update.

I exported data from Postgis using dB manager in QGIS 3 into a file which I then transferred it onto my tablet for site use.  My tablet has ArcPad 8.0 which has a project set up to read and project the above mentioned data.

When viewing the data on arcpad however it is extremely small, when zooming in the size does not change. Also I can no longer change the symbology and no longer toggle editing as the tick box for this function has disappeared.

This exercise was never an issue as I used to store my data locally and used ArcInfo for all my editing/viewing/querying/exporting

We now have been asked to store everything on a Postgis and start using QGIS.  I tried exporting the data from postgis using Arc however this did not seem to work either. Only older shape files stored locally worked, so I know it's not ArcPad. It seems as though since uploading all my data onto Postgis is doing something to the data not just storing it!

Comment: you exporting to what format? ArcPad is quite old technology (2009-2011) There is a 10.2.5 version of arcpad now are you willing to upgrade? https://support.esri.com/en/products/apps/mobile-apps/arcpad/10-2-5

Comment: Mapperz, I am exporting to Esri Shape file. The powers that be are not willing to upgrade as it will be an extra cost unfortunately, so I am stuck with 8.0..... Its not a problem as it has worked perfectly well for years of data collection.

Comment: Start by analysing a working and not-working shapefile. There must be some difference. A good start would be to run `ogrinfo -al -so` for both shapefiles.

Comment: The older shapefiles that work were also created by using QGIS and postgis in the backend? Or were those shape files created in Arc Desktop?

Comment: Hi, The older files were created in Arc Desktop.

Comment: ArcCatalog can connect to PostGIS. If that is an option, and then you can export data to a shapefile. There are just a few quick changes that need to be in place in order for ArcCatalog to interact with postgis. The steps are here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/connect-postgresql.htm If QGIS is your only option then, I would also make sure in QGIS when you are exporting feature to shape that under Layer Options RESIZE is set to NO. Maybe this was set to YES and the layer data was resized.